# Where to put fonts in yii2?

Tags: fonts, yii2, assets

I have a bootstrap 3 template and want to add its fonts (like Icons.woff) to yii2, but I dont exactly know how to out them in AppAsset class. Do we have $font as we have $css and $js? What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to kind of do it manually.

Create a folder called 'fonts' in your web directory and put your font files in there.

Go to your css directory and create new 'fonts.css' file there. Inside, you can declare your fonts using the `@font-face` rule like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font_Name_1';
    src: url('../fonts/font1.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Font_Name_2';
    src: url('../fonts/font2.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

To add this css file to your project, go to assets/AppAsset.php or to the one that you used to extended if you have such and add the new css file to the rest of the list there:

```
public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        ...,
        'css/fonts.css',
    ];
```

After that you can use your fonts in your HTML via the CSS font-family rule, something like that:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Font_Name_1', serif;
}
```

NOTE: From personal experience, it's quite important to get the `format()` right when declaring the font in the `fonts.css` file. `truetype` works for `.tff` files, `eot` works for `.eot` files, `woff` for `.woff` files, etc. Also, if you have multiple files for the same font, you should generally include them all in your `@font-face` declaration to make sure you'll have an option for each different browser.